# HTML video source switching via JavaScript matchMedia

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I am displaying a video via HTML tag `<video>`. I want to supply a small and a large video depending on the resolution of the users screen. A small screen should then only download the small video. It is no longer possible to do this with the media attribute directly in HTML. The JavaScript solution based on `matchMedia` I tried instead is not working.

I tried the following JavaScript code using matchMedia that I found in a video by Google (https://youtu.be/j5fYOYrsocs?t=356):

HTML:

```
<video>
</video>
```

JavaScript:

```
var mq = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 480px)');
if (mq.matches) {
video.src = 'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4';
}
else {
video.src = 'http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4';
}
```

This code only produces a blank page though. See this pen: https://codepen.io/blueslobster/pen/ROQjOv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Offbeatmammal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55736616/2813224) is correct in that it appears the OP has neglected to reference the video tag. In addition to a proper reference to said video, we should "listen" for changes to the viewport if we intend to adapt the video whenever the window is resized. Also, the videos in OP should be reversed, consider the following:

```
 ... const mQL = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 481px)");
```

The media query passed to the **[matchMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)** method means:

> *"Apply the following rules, expression, statement, etc. when the viewport **width is 481px or greater**"*

So when this condition is `TRUE`, the larger video should be loaded, otherwise the smaller video should be loaded:

> **if** `mQL.matches` **then** assign *larger video* to `vid.src` **else** assign *smaller video* to `vid.src`

**Note:** The first video (560x278) which matches the `mQL` (min-width: 481px) ergo is `TRUE`. The second video was changed from a huge video (854x438 which would also be true) to a video of appropriate size: (480x318). Also of note: the original media query was at 480px and changed to 481px because the best replacement video I have ATM has a natural width of 480px.
Further details are commented in Demo and **[Pen](https://codepen.io/01/pen/XQZvra?editors=0010)** (***the Demo in Full Page mode doesn't appear to work*** but it does in **[CodePen](https://codepen.io/01/pen/XQZvra?editors=0010)**, drag the window below 481px width to see the magic)

#### Demo 1

**Two videos using `.addListener()`**

```js
/*
Create a mediaQueryList Object (mQL)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList
*/
const mQL = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 481px)");

/*
Bind a listener to mQL -- triggers when window changes and calls vidSec callback function
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/addListener
*/
mQL.addListener(vidSrc);

/*
Call vidSrc() and pass mQL once to set the video src to the initial viewport. This insures
that the correct video is loaded should the viewport be less than 481px wide. Moreover
it's bad UX to start the page with an empty video tag.
*/
vidSrc(mQL);

/*
Callback function passes the mQL...
Reference the video tag...
Ternary: url is the result of [=] 
         if mQL .matches property* is [?]
         equal to or greater than 481px [TRUE]
         "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" 
         [:] else [FALSE]
         "https://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4" 
Assign url to video .src property...
load() video
*/
/* [*] .matches Property: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/matches
*/
function vidSrc(mQL) {
  const vid = document.querySelector("video");
  let url = mQL.matches ? "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" : "https://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4";
  vid.src = url;
  vid.load();
}
```

```html
<video></video>
```

#### Demo 2

#### [Pen](https://codepen.io/01/pen/GLxyqL?editors=0010)

**Three videos -- multiple mediaQueryLists in an array**

```js
const mQLs = [
  window.matchMedia(`(max-width: 854px)`),
  window.matchMedia(`(max-width: 481px)`)
];

function vidSrc(mQL) {
  const vid = document.querySelector("video");
  let url;
  if (mQLs[0].matches) {
    url = "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4";
  }
  if (mQLs[1].matches) {
    url = "https://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4";
  }
  if (!mQLs[0].matches && !mQLs[1].matches) {
    url = "http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4";
  }
  vid.src = url;
  vid.load();
}


for (let i = 0; i < mQLs.length; i++) {
  vidSrc(mQLs[i]);
}
```

```html
<video></video>
```

Comment: I removed the listener line `mQL.addListener(vidSrc);` as this line can be problematic with smartphones: when I inspected the network activity via Chrome DevTools switching a smartphone from portrait modus to landscape modus triggered a download of the bigger video even though the smaller video had been downloaded already. See this pen: https://codepen.io/pen/
Extra question: What is the best code to offer a third (and very large) video that should only play on 1080px screens and above?

Comment: See update -- **Demo 2**. Multiple mQLs in an array and function `vidSrc()` is looped.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the **width** and **height** property of the **window.screen** object to get the resolution of the screen.

```
<video id="video"></video>
```

Try Using:

```
var video = document.getElementById("video");
if (window.screen.width > 480) {
    //video source for resolution greater than 480p
    video.src = 'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4';
}else {
    //video source for resolution less than 480p
    video.src = 'http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't reference the video simply as `video` because in the javascript that variable hasn't been assigned to anything. If you define the element you want to change, then it should work:

```
<video id="vid"></video>
<script>
var mq = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 480px)');
var vid = document.getElementById("vid")
if (mq.matches) {
    vid.src = 'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4';
} else {
    vid.src = 'http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4';
} 
</script>
```

Note that the assignment of `vid` has to happen after the DOM is constructed, so either have the script after the HTML element, or only trigger at a point where you know the element has been created so it can be referenced (eg the body onloaded event for the page)